# Embeding block inside a string

Tags: ruby, string, embed

Is there any way to embed a block inside a string in a way that is executable like this?

```
for i in 1..1000
  test "There once was #{if i=1{'a man'} else {'many men'} end} from kilkenny"
end
```

Comment: `if i=1` wouldn't be a good way of testing whether `i` is equal to `1`.

Comment: In a code review, I'd contend that embedding logic inside the `#{...}` in a string is a bad practice. It's unexpected and the logic should really be performed prior to the string, assigned to a variable, and the variable interpolated into the string. It would be cleaner, clearer and easier to maintain.

Comment: yes the i=1 is incorrect an old habit from years many many years ago and another language...

Comment: It's valid, but not recommended because it can be hard to determine the intention, leading to hard to fix bugs. Yes, other languages allow it also, and in BASIC we'd test using a single `=`, but you have to force yourself to do it right, or suffer the consequences later. But, suffering those is a great way to break the habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, everything inside of `#{}` will be evaluated before the string is used, and therefore has to be valid Ruby code. Try:

```
1.upto(1000) do |i|
  puts "There once was #{i==1?"a man":"many men"} from kilkenny"
end
```

Here, I've used the ternary operator, used in Ruby and other languages, which is basically:

```
(boolean condition) ? (return this on true) : (return this on false)
```

Also note the double equal `==`, which is the equality operator in Ruby. Single equal, `=` is the assignment operator, which in your code resets the value of `i` to `1` in every loop.

Because all values except nil and false are truthy in Ruby, your proposed if .. then will always be true, because `i=1` returns `1`, which is true.

Comment: Nice that works well, thanks. I had a problem in initial for loop.

Comment: You can also use an `if` if you don't mind throwing a `then` in as well: `"... #{if i == 1 then 'a man' else 'many men' end} ... "`.

Comment: Yup, just figured I'd throw in some new stuff

Comment: Ok I see my problem = ! == I used to code way back when an if x=y was a simple test not an allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ruby's ternary operator:

```
for i in 1..1000
  puts "There once was #{i == 1 ? 'a man' : 'many men'} from kilkenny"
end
```

Comment: sure, updated - but didn't realize that was part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You already get the answer with ternary operator.

Maybe another version with the %-method gives you a better overview.
An example with three fdifferent versions:

```
1.upto(10) do |i|
  puts "There once was %s from kilkenny" % (i==1 ? "a man" : "many men")
  puts "There once was %s from kilkenny" % if i==1;  "a man"; else  "many men"; end
  puts "There once was %s from kilkenny" % case i
      when 1;  "a man" 
      else   "many men"
      end      
end
```

And you may also use a hash for your problem:

```
man = Hash.new("many men")
man[1] = "a man"
man[2] = "two men"
1.upto(10) do |i|
  puts "There once was #{man[i]} from kilkenny"
end

end
```

Or with another version of Hash-creation:

```
man = Hash.new(){|h, key|
  h[key] =case key
    when 1
      "a man"
    when 2
      "two men"
    else 
      "many men"
    end
}
1.upto(10) do |i|
  puts "There once was #{man[i]} from kilkenny"
end
```